# Add textbox values to the sharepoint choice list column

Tags: sharepoint, collections, listbox, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am a beginner in PowerApps + SharePoint List development. I have a form that contains a list of a few items. I am trying to implement a textbox for the user can add the new item if the item did not exist in the Listbox.

[image]

I am tried a few workarounds for this, But I understand there is no straightforward method to achieve this. I already found if it's a dropdown list it provides a search box for searching the items that do not exist in the items. But I want to achieve this on the Listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for doing this

> ```
> If(Not IsBlank(DataCardValue#.Selected), DataCardValue#.Selected,{Value:   DataCardValue#.SearchText,'@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"})
> ```

It works fine for me.